# How to paste append and verical aligment multiple lines text in vim?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, formatting

Is there any convenient way to format text `block-1` to `block-2` by vim?

`block-1`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include"opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "math.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
```

to

`block-2`

```
#include <stdio.h>                          #include <iostream>
#include "math.h"                           #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>                         #include <string>
#include <fstream>                <=        #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>                           #include"opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>               #include "math.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"              #include <stdio.h>
                                            #include<iostream>
```

My solution is type space one by one on each end of line，and use ctrl-v+p in command-mode to paste behand. But It's too much trouble to do this. such as i can not copy `block-1` second part at once. because of the `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` is too long.

[image: solution-1]

Comment: What about: 1) Go to the 2nd part of block1 2) `ctrl+v`+`G` to select the first column for all lines of the 2nd part 3) `$` to select all the lines no matter their length 4) Go to 1st line of 1st block 5) `A` to append at the end of the line followed by the number of whitespaces you want 6) `p` and voila?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: As statox pointed out, Visual-Block mode (with `Ctrl+V`) is the way to go. You might also be interested in the [`'virtualedit'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27) option, in particular `:set virtualedit=all`, which will allow you to navigate anywhere (regardless of line lengths) and add spaces automatically when you paste somewhere beyond the line end.